# How to get the area of segmented object from a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to get the area of a segmented object in pixels. I have the coordinates/corners (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) of the bounding box and the total area of the bounding box but my intention is to get the instance_segmentation area inside box.

i.e

[image: example]

I have the total area of the three bounding boxes, but I just want the light-blue (instance_segmentation) area of the box.

This is how I calculate the values with Mask-RCNN model:

```
  num_detections, detection_boxes, detection_classes, detection_scores,detection_masks, image_info = session.run(
      ['NumDetections:0', 'DetectionBoxes:0', 'DetectionClasses:0',
       'DetectionScores:0', 'DetectionMasks:0', 'ImageInfo:0'],
      feed_dict={'Placeholder:0': np_image_string})

  num_detections = np.squeeze(num_detections.astype(np.int32), axis=(0,))
  detection_boxes = np.squeeze(detection_boxes * image_info[0, 2], axis=(0,))[0:num_detections]
  detection_scores = np.squeeze(detection_scores, axis=(0,))[0:num_detections]
  detection_classes = np.squeeze(detection_classes.astype(np.int32), axis=(0,))[0:num_detections]
  instance_masks = np.squeeze(detection_masks, axis=(0,))[0:num_detections]
  ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = np.split(detection_boxes, 4, axis=-1)
  processed_boxes = np.concatenate([xmin, ymin, xmax - xmin, ymax - ymin], axis=-1)
  bounding_box_area = (xmax - xmin) * (ymax - ymin)
  segmentations = coco_metric.generate_segmentation_from_masks(instance_masks, processed_boxes, height, width)
  image_area = width * height
  proportion_bounding_box = (bounding_box_area / image_area)*100
```

I store the values as a dataframe in a csv file, the variable `instance_mask` stores the numpy array of the `instance_segmentation` (`Segmentation_pixels` column) i.e:

```
Bounding_box_area   Proportion_bounding_box_0_100   Segmentation_pixels
1642.33129882812    0.534613053003947            [4.7484040e-04 4.5633316e-04 1.6710162e-04 2.3344159e-04 2.5755167e-04  4.6265125e-04 7.6070428e-04 1.3544559e-03 2.2647083e-03 3.2545626e-03  4.5210123e-03 5.7159960e-03 9.2931092e-03 1.2325466e-02 2.2079408e-02  3.1557649e-02 4.6984404e-02 5.9772372e-02 8.7075949e-02 9.9743545e-02  1.4587429e-01 1.9804722e-01 2.8083831e-01 3.3062115e-01 3.5633999e-01  2.6223928e-01 1.0667321e-01 4.3513060e-02]
```

Is there a way to calculate the area of the segmented object with the numpy array?

Any suggestions will be very appreciated

Comment: I guess, you have some kind of (binary) mask for each detected object, don't you? Have a look at NumPy's [count_nonzero](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html) function, and apply it to your (binary) masks, then you should get the desired count of pixels.

Comment: @Geovani Benita use `opencv` `area = cv2.contourArea(contour)`